# Sequence & Acknowledgement numbers in TcpIp

Tags: tcp, layer4

I am confused about sequence & acknowledgement numbers of TcpIp. Here is the detail why.

1: I have two server connections and two client connections.

Client make connections at remote addresses. 
Server accepts two connections separately not those which are for clients.

So Is each client & server will manage separate unique sequence & acknowledgement number. e.g Client 1 seq=5   Client 2 sequence= 10  Server 1 sequence=17    & Server 2 sequence number =25
?

Comment: You are confusing TCP with applications. TCP doesn't have clients and servers, it has connections between peers. Applications, which are off-topic here, have clients and servers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence numbers are negotiated and incremented on a per-socket basis.  If there are two TCP sessions running between two hosts the TCP sequence numbers are completely independent.